# How to create border for image tag in svg?

Tags: html, svg, stylesheet

I tried to create border for image in svg like this :

```
<svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1054 670" xml:space="preserve">
<defs>
    <filter id="f3" x="0" y="0" width="200%" height="200%">
      <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="0" dy="1"></feOffset>
      <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="0.5"></feGaussianBlur>
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal"></feBlend>
    </filter>
  </defs>

<image overflow="visible" x="5" width="200" height="300" filter="url(#f3)" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9e/Flag_of_Japan.svg" >
    </image>    
</svg>
```

but it just a border-bottom. How can i add border top right and left. Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only getting the bottom border because you only have a single `<feOffset>` in your filter that does a shift down of the SourceAlpha. Hence only the bottom border.

If you want to stick to using filters, then you can just use four `<feOffset>` elements so you get all four borders.  In the following example I am actually shifting the offsets in the direction of each corner so that you don't get missing corner pixels.

```html
<svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1054 670" xml:space="preserve">
<defs>
    <filter id="f3">
      <feOffset result="nw" in="SourceAlpha" dx="-3" dy="-3"></feOffset>
      <feOffset result="ne" in="SourceAlpha" dx="3" dy="-3"></feOffset>
      <feOffset result="se" in="SourceAlpha" dx="3" dy="3"></feOffset>
      <feOffset result="sw" in="SourceAlpha" dx="-3" dy="3"></feOffset>
      <feMerge>
          <feMergeNode in="nw"/>
          <feMergeNode in="ne"/>
          <feMergeNode in="se"/>
          <feMergeNode in="sw"/>
          <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
        </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>

<image overflow="visible" x="5" width="200" height="300" filter="url(#f3)" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9e/Flag_of_Japan.svg" >
    </image>    
</svg>
```

The four corner-shifted SourceAlphas provide the black border.  Then we merge the original image on top.

**Update: How to change border colour**

To make the border colour something other than black, we have to add some more operations to the filter.  The simplest way is to fill the filter area with the new border colour, then mask it against the black border rectangle. Once that is done, we can merge the flag image on top as before.

```html
<svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1054 670" xml:space="preserve">
<defs>
    <filter id="f3">
        <!-- Make four copies of the image alpha, each moved to a different corner -->
        <feOffset result="nw" in="SourceAlpha" dx="-3" dy="-3"></feOffset>
        <feOffset result="ne" in="SourceAlpha" dx="3" dy="-3"></feOffset>
        <feOffset result="se" in="SourceAlpha" dx="3" dy="3"></feOffset>
        <feOffset result="sw" in="SourceAlpha" dx="-3" dy="3"></feOffset>
        <!-- Merge those four copies together -->
        <feMerge result="blackborder">
            <feMergeNode in="nw"/>
            <feMergeNode in="ne"/>
            <feMergeNode in="se"/>
            <feMergeNode in="sw"/>
        </feMerge>
        <!-- Create a filter primitive that is just a solid block of what will be
             the new border colour (in this case orange) -->
        <feFlood flood-color="orange"/>
        <!-- Use the "in" operator to merge the blackborder with the orange fill.
             Any parts of the orange fill that are "in"-side the back shape will remain.
             The rest will me masked out. -->
        <feComposite in2="blackborder" operator="in" />
        <!-- Finally, merge the new orange border with the original image -->
        <feMerge>
            <feMergeNode/>
            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
        </feMerge>
    </filter>
</defs>

<image overflow="visible" x="5" y="5" width="200" height="300" filter="url(#f3)" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9e/Flag_of_Japan.svg" >
    </image>    
</svg>
```

Comment: thanks you, This is answer i am looking, so how can i change border color. I am new in SVG

Comment: I added extra detail on how to change the colour.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau thanks it's useful, just one help border color change doesn't seem to work in safari

Comment: It's working for me in Safari.  Are you perhaps hitting this issue?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39756849/svg-filters-in-latest-safari

Comment: @PaulLeBeau ah that's interesting am on safari in  macOSX and i see problem here . Tried `Run code snippet` above and even created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/invincibleJai/kmn8of3w/

Comment: If it's the top border you are worried about, then you can fix that by moving the image down a bit to leave room for the border around the outside.  Add `y="5"`. https://jsfiddle.net/qztb1cfv/

Comment: not sure why `newcolour` was not working on safari in mac. Adding `result` in `feComposite` and passing same in `feMergeNode` instead of `newcolour` did the trick. Here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/invincibleJai/kmn8of3w/7/

Comment: Good catch. Looks like I removed "newcolour" from the feComposite, but not the feMergeNode.  The result is not needed when it is used in the next primitive.

Answer (score 0):

2 options:

1- resize the SVG element to match the image and use CSS border

2- draw a rect around your image

```
option2 jsfiddle demo:
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/re5yuacu/26/)

UPDATE:
Programmatically adding a rect as a border to your image using javascript, with resize and border color change functions:

```
function addBorders(image){
    var x = image.getAttribute("x");
    x = x ? x : 0;
    var y = image.getAttribute("y");
    y = y ? y : 0;    
    var w = image.getAttribute("width");
    var h = image.getAttribute("height");

    var g = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");    

    var rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");    
    rect.setAttribute("style","fill:white; fill-opacity:0;stroke:black; stroke-width:2px;");

    rect.id = image.id + "rect";
    console.log(rect.id);
    rect.setAttribute("x",x);
    rect.setAttribute("y",y);
    rect.setAttribute("width",w);
    rect.setAttribute("height",h);


    var parent = image.parentNode;
    parent.insertBefore(g,image);
    g.appendChild(image);
    g.insertBefore(rect,image.nextSibling);

}

function redrawBorder(rect,w,h){
    rect.setAttribute("width",w);
    rect.setAttribute("height",h);    
}

window.updatePosition = function(image,x,y){

    document.getElementById(image.id + "rect")
    image.setAttribute("x",x);
    image.setAttribute("y",y);
    moveBorder(image.nextSibling,x,y);

}

function moveBorder(rect,x,y){
    rect.setAttribute("x",x);
    rect.setAttribute("y",y);    
}

window.updateSize = function(image,w,h){

    document.getElementById(image.id + "rect")
    image.setAttribute("width",w);
    image.setAttribute("height",h);
    redrawBorder(image.nextSibling,w,h);

}

window.updateColor = function(image,color){

     document.getElementById(image.id + "rect").style.stroke=color;
}


var image = document.getElementById("image1");
addBorders(image);
```

Demo:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/re5yuacu/142/)

Comment: thanks you but i am looking for another way because i need show many image with other size

Comment: I updated my answer, the JS function will draw a rect around your image regardless of its position or size. please check the jsfiddle below the code, change the image x/y/hight/width values to see the effect. you can also change the rect style to change colors , maked dashed , dotted ...etc. hope that helps

Comment: I have think about this way but have a problem in svg image is if width or height of <image> less than original size of image then  image will auto resize and rect element just create will not true.

Comment: Do you mean that the image goes on top of the border if it's too small? I updated the code & jsfiddle to solve this issue. please take a look

Comment: yeah thanks this is also a good way, i had tried create rect like you but it not display correct